# Can't install zfsutils-linux on newest Raspbian (July 2017)

Tags: zfs, dkms

Yesterday I installed the newest Raspbian on my SD card. Today I wanted to install all the packages needed for [ZFSonLinux](http://zfsonlinux.org/). First I installed spl-dkms, zfs-dkms, etc. Everything went fine. Then I wanted to install zfsutils-linux but it failed with the following message:

```
root@hostname:/home/pi/Downloads# dpkg -i zfsutils-linux_0.6.5.11-1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 65248 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack zfsutils-linux_0.6.5.11-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.11-1) over (0.6.5.11-1) ...
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.11-1) ...
Job for zfs-import-scan.service failed. See 'systemctl status zfs-import-scan.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed. See 'systemctl status zfs-mount.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Job for zfs-share.service failed. See 'systemctl status zfs-share.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
```

Note: every package directly associated with ZFS is of the version `0.6.5.11-1`.

Here the output of `journalctl -xn`:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2017-07-23 13:47:34 UTC, end at Sun 2017-07-23 14:23:16 UTC. --
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
-- Subject: Unit zfs-mount.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit zfs-mount.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Unit zfs-mount.service entered failed state.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Starting ZFS file system shares...
-- Subject: Unit zfs-share.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit zfs-share.service has begun starting up.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: zfs-share.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start ZFS file system shares.
-- Subject: Unit zfs-share.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit zfs-share.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Unit zfs-share.service entered failed state.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Starting ZFS startup target.
-- Subject: Unit zfs.target has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit zfs.target has begun starting up.
Jul 23 14:22:00 hostname systemd[1]: Reached target ZFS startup target.
-- Subject: Unit zfs.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit zfs.target has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Output of `systemctl status zfs-mount.service`:

```
    ● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2017-07-23 14:26:59 UTC; 3min 38s ago
      Process: 4382 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=ILL)
     Main PID: 4382 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

    Jul 23 14:26:59 hostname systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
    Jul 23 14:26:59 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
    Jul 23 14:26:59 hostname systemd[1]: Unit zfs-mount.service entered failed state.
```

Also everytime I try to use the `zpool` command in any way it states `Illegal instruction`, but I've never seen this error before on the old installation and with the older ZFS package. Besides that the newest ZFS packages are already adjusted to the newest kernel as far as I know.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently the problem lies in Raspbian but I still didn't find the exact reason. I just tried to install `php5-fpm` and this was the output:

```
 ● php5-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2017-07-23 23:08:44 UTC; 31s ago
  Process: 21459 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
  Process: 21453 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21459 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

Jul 23 23:08:43 hostname php5-fpm-checkconf[21453]: Illegal instruction
Jul 23 23:08:44 hostname systemd[1]: php5-fpm.service: main process exited, cod...LL
Jul 23 23:08:44 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Ma...r.
Jul 23 23:08:44 hostname systemd[1]: Unit php5-fpm.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Output of `strace zpool list`:

```
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26672, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 90684, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6b2c000
mprotect(0xb6b32000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6b41000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0xb6b41000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0p<\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 434644, SEEK_SET)              = 434644
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 434312, SEEK_SET)              = 434312
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=435804, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 499856, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6ab1000
mprotect(0xb6b1a000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6b2a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x69000) = 0xb6b2a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\220\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8660, SEEK_SET)                = 8660
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8328, SEEK_SET)                = 8328
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9820, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6a9e000
mprotect(0xb6aa0000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6aaf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xb6aaf000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6a9d000
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6a9b000
set_tls(0xb6a9b4c0, 0xb6a9cbe8, 0xb6fec058, 0xb6a9b4c0, 0xb6fec058) = 0
mprotect(0xb6c7e000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6aaf000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6b2a000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6ca9000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6b41000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6cd2000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6ce6000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6d2b000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f87000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6fa5000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6d40000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6e79000, 12288, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0xb6d7f000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6fa7000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0xb6fa7000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
cacheflush(0xb6fa7000, 0xb6fac000, 0, 0x15, 0xbe9a3378) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5b2000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6feb000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6fdc000, 51848)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xb6a9b068)             = 10780
set_robust_list(0xb6a9b070, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0xb6c8a434, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0xb6b721a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0xb6c8a2d8, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0xb6b721a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
--- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPC, si_addr=0xb6f675a4} ---
+++ killed by SIGILL +++
```

Comment: have you tried reverting to the 0.6.5.10 or 0.6.5.9 versions of the zfs packages?

Comment: I didn't try that because I'm not sure if they are compatible with the 4.9 kernel.

Comment: they are.  zfs compatibility, IME, has only been an issue when there's a new kernel.  e.g. zfs-dkms 0.6.5.9-0.6.5.11 work with kernel 4.9 but if you want kernel 4.10 or higher you needed zfs-dkms 0.6.5.10 or .11.  and even that isn't every kernel version, it's only when something in the kernel changes incompatibly, requiring zfs to be modified to suit.  This is the case on amd64 kernels, anyway.  I don't have an rpi, so can't confirm that it's the same there (my guess is it would be).

Comment: btw, at the moment i have got 2 systems running zfs 0.6.5.10 on kernel 4.11, 1 system running zfs 0.6.5.9 on kernel 4.9, and 1 system running zfs 0.6.5.11 which has been crashing on both kernel 4.10 and 4.11 since I installed 0.6.5.11 a few days ago (fortunately it's my zfs test box, which is why it's the only one with 0.6.5.11).  I haven't had time yet to figure out whether it's a coincidental hardware fault (ancient hardware on this test box) or if it's due to zfs 0.6.5.11

Comment: I changed now everything to version *0.6.5.9*. The exact same problem still arises.

Comment: OK, that sounds like it might be a problem with one of the core libraries.  Perhaps `libc` or `libpthread`.  You could maybe narrow it down by checking which libs are common to both `zpool` and `php5-fpm`.   e.g. with something like  `ldd /usr/sbin/php5-fpm | grep -F -f <(ldd /sbin/zpool | cut -d' ' -f1)`.  and then try re-installing or upgrading those libraries.

Comment: you could also try running something like `strace zpool list` to find out exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: Sadly Raspbian claims to have neither libc, nor libpthread, at all...

Comment: they were just examples.  and raspbian has both, they're essential on any modern general-purpose linux system.  what model of rpi is it?  is the raspbian you're using compiled for that model or some earlier or newer model?